# How to do this list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

Let's say that I start with the list:

```py
list1 = [['a', '1', '2'], ['b', '1'], ['c'], ['d']]
```

and the tuple:

```py
b = (1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Now I want to get a list like:

```py
c = [['a', '1', '2'], ['b', '1', '1'], ['b', '1', '2'], ['b', '1', '3'], ['b', '1', '4'], ['c'], ['d']]
```

so every part of `b` extends a new copy of the old nested list in which `b` is.

So basically what I want is something like:

```py
c = [i + [j] for j in b if "b" in i else i for i in a]            (1)
```

Sadly that doesnt work.

So I tried:

```py
c = [[i + [j] for j in b] if "b" in i else i for i in a]
```

which gives me:

```py
[['a', '1', '2'], [['b', '1', 1], ['b', '1', 2], ['b', '1', 3], ['b', '1', 4]], ['c'], ['d']]
```

I tried then to split this again but I didn't manage it.

My best try was:

```py
[i[x] if type(i[0]) is list else i for i in c for x in range(len(i))]
```

Is there maybe a way to make (1) just work or to get the list I get into the result I want? I am kinda stuck. Probably it's quite easy but I don't see the way.

Comment: Seems a bit complicated to do with comprehensions, since you want to add more than one item per iteration, so I guess you either flatten the list after or do it imperatively, with a list.append() in case there is no "b" or several list.append() in case there is a "b".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would avoid list comprehensions for something this complex:

```
list1 = [['a', '1', '2'], ['b', '1'], ['c'], ['d']]

b = (1, 2, 3, 4)

new_list = []
for i in list1:
    if 'b' in i:
        extended = [i + [str(j)] for j in b]
        new_list += extended
    else:
        new_list.append(i)
```

Comment: This does the trick perfectly fine! I was just stuck in training comprehensions but i guess sometimes it makes life harder to use them:D

Comment: Yep, Python is not very good as a functional language. In other languages you have things like flatMap which makes this trivial.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want a list comprehension you could try

```
list1 = [['a', '1', '2'], ['b', '1'], ['c'], ['d']]
b = (1, 2, 3, 4)
c = list1.copy()  # to ensure we don't modify list1
c[1:2] = [list1[1] + [i] for i in b]
```

Comment: instead of using hard coded index like c[1:2] I suggest you to use a dynamic way to find index of the object in the list which contains 'b'. That would change the line no 4 as `c[b_index:b_index+1] = [list1[b_index] + [i] for i in b]`

Comment: I didnt mention it in the question thats my fault but i dont know where the list with the b is in the beginning and if there are multiple nested lists with a b wich then should be all treated the same. But i guess Dan's answer does the trick just gonna do no comprehension then. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2):

```
list1 = [['a', '1', '2'], ['b', '1'], ['c'], ['d']]
b = (1, 2, 3, 4)

b_index = list(filter(lambda index: 'b' in list1[index], range(len(list1))))[0] # searx for list which contains b

list1[b_index] = [list1[b_index]+[item] for item in b]
print (list1)
```

output:

```
[['a', '1', '2'], [['b', '1', 1], ['b', '1', 2], ['b', '1', 3], ['b', '1', 4]], ['c'], ['d']]
```

Answer (score 0):

The missing step you wanted - to split the result of (1) would be:

```
reduce(lambda x, y: (x if isinstance(x[0], list) else [x]) +
                    (y if isinstance(y[0], list) else [y]),
       [[i + [str(j)] for j in b] if "b" in i else i for i in a])
```

Or more readably:

```
def unnest(x):
    return x if isinstance(x[0], list) else [x]

# Your original (1) attempt (just adding str):
c = [[i + [str(j)] for j in b] if "b" in i else i for i in a]

result = reduce(lambda x, y: unnest(x) + unnest(y), c)
```

But as Dan suggests, avoiding list comprehension might be even more readable in this case.